# Can we use a solenoid as an endless energy source?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion

If we pass a magnet inside a cylindrical pvc pipe on which copper wire is mounted. Then is it possible to conduct the current if the magnet is on a piston and piston is connected with a camshaft?

Answer (score 0):

You've described a linear alternator. This is how those shake flashlights work. I suppose you can call it "endless" if you keep the source of energy going (shaking, reciprocating piston) "endlessly." It is just converting some of the kinetic energy into electrical energy.

Comment: It means it is possible. Isn't it?

Comment: It is possible to generate electrical energy from mechanical motion using this mechanism. However, just to be clear, it is not creating "free" energy. The mechanical energy input will be greater than the electrical energy output.

Comment: . And suppose we connect a flywheel with the cam shaft which will conserve the angular momentum then would it be possible?

Comment: Will what be possible? You can add as many flywheels or other mechanical devices as you want, but your solenoid is not going to ever create "free" energy. As I stated above, the energy input will always be greater than the energy output.

Comment: Can we increase the rate of output electrical energy by by using some electrical devices like transformers, rectifiers etc.?